# Using the Mechanical Turk API to get a worker's country

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is there any way to query the Amazon Mechanical Turk API in order to find out the country of a particular worker who has completed one of your HIT's (or at least to determine whether or not they live in the United States)? I believe QualificationTypeId 00000000000000000071 represents the worker's location, but calling the GetQualificationScore operation with that ID results in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve workers' scores for built-in qualification types. You can use them as Qualification Requirements though, and - for example - restrict a HIT to just US people or create multiple identical HITs with each open only to one country.

Comment: Thanks. That what I suspected -- just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.